# Python imports-Need someone to check this please

Tags: python, import

Ok yes it is a very silly question, but just that I am getting a little confused.
I have a file structure which looks like this:-

```
-Mainapplication
   -models.py
-Helpingmodules
   -Folder1
     -module1.py
```

Now I have to import models into module1. So in module1.py I just did:-

```
from Mainapplication import models
```

Now this does work fine, but I get a feeling that it might be wrong. Can someone please let me know if this is the correct way.

Comment: "I get a feeling that it might be wrong"  Why?  It works perfectly.  Are you worried about your `PYTHONPATH` setting?

Comment: other than importing you r main application into a helping module, I see no issues

Comment: Thanks S.Lott and SilentGhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the import, but if the names of your packages are accurate, this looks like a design flaw in that you're destroying code reusability; I'd expect a package of "helping modules" to be independent of the application they're helping (although in the case the package name is so vague that I could be way off about their purpose.)

Comment: Thanks Woobie, yes the names of the packages are not correct.But yes the concept of reusability pointed me to something here..

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your `import`.

You *could* say:

```
import Mainapplication.models
```

but then you'd have to reference `models` with its Package prefix every time you used it, e.g.:

```
Mainapplication.models.foo("bar")
```

The way you've done it allows you to use the following form which is usually preferable:

```
models.foo("bar")
```

For the full story you can [read the documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages).